# Access conditional hyperlink

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in datasheet view, on which the first column displays the autonumber primary key of the records displayed.

This field appears as a hyperlink which is used to open a form to manipulate the data of the record.

I would like this hyperlink to open one of two different forms, depending on whether a particular field is null or not.

This is the code I use to open the form to the relevant record

```
Private Sub ISP_ID_Click()

    TempVars.Add "CurrentRecord", ISP_ID.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmModifyISP", acNormal, "", "[ISP_ID]=[TempVars]![CurrentRecord]", acEdit, acNormal

End Sub
```

I would like to open a form named "frmModifyISP_Address" if a field called "AddressID" for the current record is not null.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Private Sub ISP_ID_Click()

    If IsNull(Me!AddressID.Value) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmModifyISP_Address"
    Else
        TempVars.Add "CurrentRecord", ISP_ID.Value
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmModifyISP", acNormal, "", "[ISP_ID]=[TempVars]![CurrentRecord]", acEdit, acNormal
    End If

End Sub
```

Or lookup the value:

```
Private Sub ISP_ID_Click()

    If IsNull(DLookup("AddressID", "YourTable", "ID = " & Me!ISP_ID.Value & "")) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmModifyISP_Address"
    Else
        TempVars.Add "CurrentRecord", ISP_ID.Value
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmModifyISP", acNormal, "", "[ISP_ID]=[TempVars]![CurrentRecord]", acEdit, acNormal
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, should have explained myself in more detail. 

The datasheet view form on which the hyperlink sits is based on a query. The AddressID field does not appear on the form itself, it is instead on a table which the ISP_ID field is the primary key of.

So what I think I'm looking for is a way to Access to grab the specific ISP_ID that has been clicked, go to the table and check whether the relevant record has a value entered into the AddressID field, and then open the correct form.

Comment: OK. If so, try to look up the value.